# How to make web site menus

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a menu on my website.
If I move my mouse on it, the menu strip and its item will appear; if I move out of the menu the items disappear and only the menu name will remain.
Using visual web developer 2008 express edition and c#.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use a jQuery menu. They are easy to use, and there are many that are freely available. Here is [just one example](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryMenu), there are many.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the asp.net menu control. You can find informations on the MSDN on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) .

Asp.net menu can be easily linked to the site map to show your pages. The folding effect seems to be supported.
[Example](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/WalkThru/SimpleMenu.aspx) from [here](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/WalkThru/WalkThrough.aspx#SimpleMenu)

Answer (score 0):

Which type of menus you want to create ?

Either Jquery static menus or Dynamic Menus ?

If you want jquery menus you can just google it out and you can get the best designed menus.

And if you are willing to create dynamic Menus in VS2008 which will be populated by database then you can visit this link

[Dynamic Menus with Submenus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733918/asp-net-3-5-c-best-way-to-create-and-display-dynamic-menu-with-submenus/10320299)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery menus are the best and easy to use.

The best menu control that i have used is Superfish it is lightweight.

you can try out.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/